# How do i break out of this while loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, break

```
def main():
  dmn_options = ["lenovo", "rasbberrypi", "Exit"]
  while True:
    display_menu(dmn_options)
    user_choice = select_single_l(dmn_options);print(user_choice)
    
  
def display_menu(options):
  print("Select an option:")
  for index, option in enumerate(options, start=1):
    print(f"{index}. {option}")

def select_single_l(options):
  choice=None
  while True:
    try:
      i = int(input("Enter the number of your choice: "))
      if 1 <= i <= len(options) - 1:
        choice=options[i - 1]
        print(f"You selected {choice}.")
        break
      elif i == len(options):
        print("Exiting the menu.")
        break
      else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please enter a valid number.")
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
    break
  return choice
```

I've tried chatGPT but to no avail. I tell the code to break but it does not break - it is frustrating. When the user select `Exit` it is meant to stop selecting - mimicking Bash's select statement. Please help.

Comment: There are two `while` loops in the code you presented (which incidentally won't do anything, since there's nothing calling the functions -- provide proper [mcve]), which one do you have in mind?

Comment: You have two loops here - which one?

Comment: A `break` in `select_single_l` does not break out of the loop in `main`.

Comment: If it's the first one, then there is no break. If you want it to respond to the exit choice, you will need to do something more with `user_choice`, beyond just printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue stems from you not exiting your main() while loop

```
def main():
  dmn_options = ["lenovo", "rasbberrypi", "Exit"]
  while True:
    display_menu(dmn_options)
    user_choice = select_single_l(dmn_options);print(user_choice)
```

Here is an example doing so without altering your original code too much.

```
def main():
  dmn_options = ["lenovo", "rasbberrypi", "Exit"]
  while True:
    display_menu(dmn_options)
    user_choice = select_single_l(dmn_options);print(user_choice)
    if user_choice == None:
      break
    
  
def display_menu(options):
  print("Select an option:")
  for index, option in enumerate(options, start=1):
    print(f"{index}. {option}")

def select_single_l(options):
  choice=None
  while True:
    try:
      i = int(input("Enter the number of your choice: "))
      if 1 <= i <= len(options) - 1:
        choice=options[i - 1]
        print(f"You selected {choice}.")
        break
      elif i == len(options):
        print("Exiting the menu.")
        break
      else:
        print("Invalid choice. Please enter a valid number.")
    except ValueError:
      print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
    break
  return choice
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you make an invalid choice such as `0` before deciding to quit.

Comment: You are correct. I just opted to not touch anything outside of the original main function to help OP see where the issue was originating. A simple fix for this would be including something like "choice = i" in the else portion of select_single_l

Answer (score 1):

Return the user input from `select_single_l` and use that to make a breaking decision in `main`.

```
def main():
  dmn_options = ["lenovo", "rasbberrypi", "Exit"]
  while True:
    display_menu(dmn_options)
    user_choice = select_single_l(dmn_options)
    print(user_choice)
    if user_choice == dmn_options[-1]:
        break
def select_single_l(options):
  while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("Enter the number of your choice: "))
        if 1 <= choice <= len(options):
            return options[choice - 1]
        print("Invalid choice. Please enter a valid number.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a number.")
```